# Selenium Python : NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to scrape images from Bing. I am using Selenium and trying to extract source links of the images.

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com/images")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("wheat zinc deficiency")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("mimg").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/span/span/img").click()
```

The last line is showing error, which is

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element

I have tried to avoid race condition by waiting for the page to load.
I got the xpath using firebug add-on for firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image opens in `iframe`, so to handle it you need to switch to that `iframe` first:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("mimg").click()
driver.switch_to_frame('OverlayIFrame')
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@class="mainImage accessible nofocus"]')
print(image.get_attribute('src'))
```